# How to get the batch size in a custom TensorFlow (2.0) Keras Model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tf.keras

I'm subclassing `tf.keras.model`. I need to override `compute_output_shape`, as otherwise, I end up with a `NotImplementedError` from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.0/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py#L489).

```
class Custom(tf.keras.Model):
    ...

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        # input_shape = (None, ...)
        batch_size = ???
        return (batch_size, ...)
```

`compute_output_shape` takes `input_shape` as input. However, that's not of much help, as the batch size somehow gets lost in TensorFlow somewhere.

If I try returning a shape that starts with `None` in the same way as `input_shape`, I get `TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`. Just omitting the batch size doesn't work either.

The batch size is variable, so I cannot just hard-code it.

Comment: There is no need for `compute_output_shape`, all you need is `call` method. There must be something wrong with your code which is not related to `compute_output_shape`.

Comment: @SzymonMaszke Did you look at the link?

Comment: Yes, still I have never encountered the need to write `compute_output_shape`. You should look a little higher in the link you provided, [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.0/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py#L456) exactly, which would tell you that you are not running eagerly (which is strange as it's default TF2.0 mode). That's why I don't think it's the cause of your issues. Usually one calls build with specified `input_shape` after model creation and it's enough. It might be the `NotImplemented` error above it, in which case your custom layer might be an issue

Comment: @SzymonMaszke I guess it's not running eagerly because even in TF2.0, Keras models are executed in graph mode. (I did pass `dynamic=True` to my custom model, but it's being used by another model created through the functional API.)